# Erro em projeto: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' - JavaParaWeb

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-security

Estou estudando Java pelo livro "Java para Web 2º Ed.", estava indo tranquilo, porém parei no seguinte erro:

```html
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:financeiro' did not find a matching property.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Nov 27 2017 13:05:30 UTC
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.5.24.0
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 10
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            10.0
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Desenvolvimento\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Desenvolvimento\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.24
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:55648
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Desenvolvimento\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Desenvolvimento\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.24
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Desenvolvimento\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Desenvolvimento\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\endorsed
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php-7.1;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Desenvolvimento\IDE\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 1679 ms
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
ADVERTÊNCIA:   No rules found matching 'Context/Context/Resource'.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
ADVERTÊNCIA:   No rules found matching 'Context/Context'.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:37 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
ADVERTÊNCIA:   No rules found matching 'Context/Context/Resource'.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
ADVERTÊNCIA:   No rules found matching 'Context/Context'.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: Name = FinanceiroDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "DataSource FinanceiroDB" for "description" property
abr 12, 2018 11:39:42 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
abr 12, 2018 11:39:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
abr 12, 2018 11:39:42 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMAÇÕES: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
abr 12, 2018 11:39:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 12 23:39:42 GFT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
abr 12, 2018 11:39:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:43 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFORMAÇÕES: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.6.RELEASE
abr 12, 2018 11:39:43 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFORMAÇÕES: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.6.RELEASE
abr 12, 2018 11:39:43 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFORMAÇÕES: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFORMAÇÕES: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1cfaa581: defining beans [financeiroDataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
abr 12, 2018 11:39:44 PM org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao
INFORMAÇÕES: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:44 PM org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao
INFORMAÇÕES: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:44 PM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFORMAÇÕES: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5d3c346f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@27a28932, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@472f45e6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@37b557bb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@b96826e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@38ce6137, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@57313bd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@18e68427, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@275cf0a7, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6cd0eaa2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7123f27e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5dc887c1]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:44 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFORMAÇÕES: Checking whether login URL '/publico/login.jsf' is accessible with your configuration
abr 12, 2018 11:39:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMAÇÕES: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2141 ms
abr 12, 2018 11:39:45 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMAÇÕES: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) para o contexto '/financeiro'
abr 12, 2018 11:39:45 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: JSF1048: Anotações PostConstruct/PreDestroy presentes.  Os métodos ManagedBeans marcados com essas anotações informarão as anotações processadas.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:45 PM com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl getProjectStage
INFORMAÇÕES: Unable to discern ProjectStage for value Development>.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor getProjectStage
INFORMAÇÕES: Unable to discern ProjectStage for value Development>.
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
abr 12, 2018 11:39:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
abr 12, 2018 11:39:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
abr 12, 2018 11:39:47 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
abr 12, 2018 11:39:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
abr 12, 2018 11:39:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
abr 12, 2018 11:39:47 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
at br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
at br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
at br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.init(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:22)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
... 23 more

abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
at br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
at br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
at br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.init(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:22)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
... 23 more

abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
abr 12, 2018 11:39:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 15717 ms
```

Pelo que entendi, está tentando acessar um banco local(?), porém no livro não citou nenhuma criação de banco local. Por favor, alguém poderia me dizer o que está acontecendo?

O meu projeto, que é de estudo, está disponível publicamente, caso queiram testar para averiguarem, segue o link em baixo.

[Projeto de Estudo - Financeiro - Java WEB GitLab](https://gitlab.com/filipelobato/financeiro)

Comment: No seu arquivo hibernate.cfg.xml, toda a parte de comunicação com o banco de dados está comentada! Tire o comentário se a configuração estiver correta,  e se você configurou o ambiente direitinho irá funcionar.

Comment: @Edjane obrigado, mudou de erro ;x. Está dando o seguinte erro: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource" log: https://pastebin.com/raw/VcsrGa0B

Comment: Você criou o banco de dados no seu mysql?

Comment: Sim, estava criado, consegui avançar, obrigado!